# How to construct hover text without disabling geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

The code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df<-data.frame(replicate(2,sample(2000,size=29,replace=TRUE)))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X1, y=X2*1000,text=X1))+geom_point()+geom_smooth()
p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
print(p)
```

produces the expected plot with smoothed line as well as points over which a mouse hover displays the value of X1.

However, replacing the ggplot call with:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=X1, y=X2*1000,text=paste0("X1=",X1)))
```

fails to produce the smoothed line, although it does the expected on mouse hover.

Is this a bug?

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just putting the aesthetics `text` inside the aesthetic specifications of `geom_point`. It should let you customize your tooltip. Despite producing a warning "Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text",  it will create the desired tooltip. Check another [example](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/interactive-tooltip/) in the plotly official page, using `text` inside `geom_point`'s aesthetics.

```
df<-data.frame(replicate(2, sample(2000, size = 29, replace = TRUE)))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = X2 * 1000)) +  
  geom_point(aes(text = paste0("X1=", X1, " X2=", X2, " Whatever needed"))) +
  geom_smooth() 
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

**EDIT: Tooltips for geom_smooth**

If we want to display tooltips for geom_smooth, we need a different approach. We need the `style()` function to modify trace attribute values in a plotly object.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(2, sample(2000, size = 29, replace = TRUE)))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = X2 * 1000))
w <-  ggplotly(p + geom_point() + geom_smooth())

text_1 <-  paste0("Text geom_point:", "<br />", "X1=", w$x$data[[1]]$x, "<br />", "X2=", w$x$data[[1]]$y)
text_2 <-  paste0("Text geom_smooth:", "<br />" , w$x$data[[2]]$text)
w %>% 
    style(text= text_1, traces = 1) %>% 
     style(text = text_2, traces = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: No, I actually want a complex string containing county, state, a variable's value and a description of the value.  I guess that's what I get for trying to make a minimal example for stackoverflow.

Comment: @user3673 I modified my answer. Please let me know if this works for the real problem you dealing with.

Comment: "Warning:  Ignoring unknown parameters: text"  Never mind, I've found a workaround.  I'll post it.

Comment: OK, ignoring the error message works.  I'll delete my work around and accept your answer.  Please add a `print` at the end to complete the code.

Comment: @mpalanco Do you know how to create hover text for `geom_smooth`? Thanks.

Comment: @mihagazvoda I have edited my answer to add custom tooltips for geom_smooth

Comment: Is there a way to make this work if you add colors to the points separated by a factor? When I do that only some colors show the tooltip, and it actually shows the geom_smooth tooltip for points and the normal text box for the line.

Comment: I figured this is because w$x$data is now split into many different groups each representing one of the factors, but it's annoying to iterate through all of them.